# iOS - HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn vertical alignment

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uifont

I am using one font named HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtCn in my iPhone app,
but I find out that the vertical alignment of that font is strange. There is padding below the text:

[image]

The result is that the bottom padding of table view cell is bigger than top. What can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this post to fix it http://www.andyyardley.com/2012/04/24/custom-ios-fonts-and-how-to-fix-the-vertical-position-problem/

1.Download and install "Apple Font Tool Suite"

2.Generate the font setting xml file

```
ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A d font.ttf
```

3.Change the following "ascender" and "descender" setting in the output xml.

```
ascender="975"
descender="-227"
```

4.Adjust the font file by

```
ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A f font.ttf
```

Your font file will be vertical-centered.

Comment: I'll give it a try in my next iOS project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using my own cell, and moving the labels down.